# this.http.get('....../contacts.json') - property 'map' does not exist on type 'observable<object>'

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object, contacts

i try to get my contacts-array loaded and want to loop them.
The problem is, that i receive the contacts as an object and not as an array, so i can't use .map.
This is my code snippet:

```
loadConJSON() {
    this.http.get('../../assets/data/contacts.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
```

This results in the following error:

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'observable<object>'
```

This is the content of contacts.json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_objectInstance": {
        "id": 383,
        "name": {
          "givenName": "",
          "honorificSuffix": "",
          "formatted": "Schmidt",
          "middleName": "",
          "familyName": "Schmidt",
          "honorificPrefix": ""
        }, ...
```

How can convert the object into an array?

EDIT:
I want to do something like this (build new array):

```
let contactsArray = contacts.map(contacts => 
({ id: contacts.id, 
familyName: contacts.name.familyName, 
email: contacts.email.value }));
```

Comment: have you tried this.http.get('../../assets/data/contacts.json')["data"].map(...)? using typescript?

Comment: than i receive the following error: "undefined" is not an object

Comment: if you console.log(this.http.get('../../assets/data/contacts.json')), what is the output?

Comment: The output is an observable, see here a screenshot: https://ibb.co/ekPYyS

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following line on top of your code:

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Alternatively, use [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md), which are recommended since recent versions of Angular/RxJS.

Comment: see the edit of the org. post: is it possible to build new array with RxJS? and if so, how do i do that?